# jsp to pdf in java with itext

Tags: java, jsp, pdf

I have searched for a solution but so far nothing gives me the answer i want. My question is how to convert an existing jsp page to pdf using itext possibly after clicking a button. Can someone give me a proper exaple.

All i can find is methods like this.

```
public String createHtmlSnippet(Movie movie) {
    StringBuffer buf = new StringBuffer("\t<span class=\"title\">");
    buf.append(movie.getMovieTitle());
    buf.append("</span><br />\n");
    buf.append("\t<ul>\n");
    for (Country country : movie.getCountries()) {
        buf.append("\t\t<li class=\"country\">");
        buf.append(country.getCountry());
        buf.append("</li>\n");
    }
    buf.append("\t</ul>\n");
    buf.append("\tYear: <i>");
    buf.append(movie.getYear());
    buf.append(" minutes</i><br />\n");
    buf.append("\tDuration: <i>");
    buf.append(movie.getDuration());
    buf.append(" minutes</i><br />\n");
    buf.append("\t<ul>\n");
    for (Director director : movie.getDirectors()) {
        buf.append("\t\t<li><span class=\"director\">");
        buf.append(director.getName());
        buf.append(", ");
        buf.append(director.getGivenName());
        buf.append("</span></li>\n");
    }
    buf.append("\t</ul>\n");
    return buf.toString();
}
```

I want to give the url and generate and download the pdf.

Comment: That is one of the problems im facing. Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

You can call a servlet on the button click. And in the servlet the you can use PDF Renderer. It converts HTML to PDF directly. although it has certain Restrictions like all tags should be closed like doing this `<input/>`  wont work .

You would have to do `<input></input>`. But the output is amazing and fast and since it HTML you can change it easily. It internally uses iText. If you use iText directly then it would be a tedious process.

**And your question should be HTML to PDF not JSP to PDf cause the JSP will get execute to produce some HTML in the end anyways**

You entire HTML should be in the StringBuffer or String format.

Download from [here](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/c/Downloadcomspringsourcecomlowagietextsources208jar.htm)

**Update Code:**

```
// First create a temporry file
        File file = File.createTempFile("temp","pdf");
        String html= "<HMTL><BODY>Hello</BODY></HTML>"; // HTML content

    /* in your case it would be File f = new File("URL OF PAGE");
     * */
    // Write the contents intot he file.
    PrintWriter printWriter = new PrintWriter(file);
    printWriter.print(html); // Write String in Temp file
    printWriter.close();

    String s ="YourFile.pdf"; // Name of Actual PDf file
    PDFRenderer.renderToPDF(file,s);// Second parameter is the actual PDF file
    // The PDF is now created in the default location of you web application
    // Now just read it and send it in the response.
    File finalPDf = new File(s); // Reference to the newly created PDF file
    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
    response.setContentType("application/pdf");
    IOUtils.copy(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(s)), out); 
    // The above method just reads from the PDF file and puts the data in the response object
    // IOUtils fully qualified name: org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils
    // PDF Renderer fully qualified name: org.xhtmlrenderer.simple.PDFRenderer
```

Comment: The OP states `I want to give the url and generate and download the pdf.`  How does your solution address that?  I guess your way can be called via JS or Jquery - right?

Comment: Yup. I think you can just pass the URL of the Page to the render instead of the string. This should would. I'll have to refer the docs to be sure. My above mentioned methods works fine I have tested it.

Comment: can you please provide an example ??

Comment: sure Give me some time

Answer (score -1):

I had same requirement Docx4j worked for me.It has lot of helpers [docx4j documentation](http://www.docx4java.org/docx4j/Docx4j_GettingStarted.pdf)